# Using VLOOKUP in an Excel 2007 VBA Function

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have tried hours and hours of examples but I continually get the same error of #NAME?

I need to use VLOOKUP within a VBA function and then work with the result before putting the result to a cell. Firstly I am having a problem just to get the VBA VLOOKUP part working.

For testing here is the details
Spreadsheet is...

Worksheet = Sheet1

4 rows x 2 columns of data. 
    Cells D1:E4
    Dance : 23
    French : 42
    English : 2
Music : 33

In cell A1 I will have a user imputed content that will a value from column D eg French

In Cell B1 I will call the function 
    =GetQty(A1,D1:E4,2)
but I always get #NAME?

1) How do I call the function properly. Am I doing this corretly?

In my VBA function "GetQty" I just want to do the VLOOKUP on a value of cell A1 and return the value from the matching entry from the table(Cell D1:E4), eg return 42 and then place that value into column B1 and (also column C1 via the VBA and not just using a formula in the worksheet cell of =B1 )

Here is one of the many examples I have tried in my function just to get the VLOOKUP to work.

```
Function GetQty(Celly As Range, CellyRange As Range, Colretval As Integer) As Integer
Dim result As String
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
GetQty = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sheet.Range(CellyRange), sheet.Range(CellyTable), Colretval, False)
End Function
```

I have tried many examples but I always get #NAME? error

Comment: I don't see any advantage using a UDF over the native VLOOKUP function   here ! It will just be much slower. Do you have any reason for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues, mainly:

- First argument for Vlookup cannot be a range, needs to be a value
- It's safer to not declare the return type as Integer

Here's a working example of how to use Vlookup from VBA, maybe it'll help (you call it just VLookup):

```
Function VBAVlookup(ByVal search As Variant, _
                    cell_range As Range, _
                    offset As Long, _
                    Optional opt As Boolean = False)

Dim result As Variant
result = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(search, cell_range, offset, opt)
'do some cool things to result

VBAVlookup = result

End Function
```

Unless what you are doing is rather sophisticated, you can always use `=Vlookup(...) * 55 +2`  and stuff like that to return a manipulated result from vlookup using just one formula.

Comment: I have tried the above function, change the call to the function from the worksheet to include a value instead of a cell reference but I still getting #NAME? error. I have tried =VBAVlookup("French",$D$1:$E$4,2) and also =VBAVlookup("French",D1:E4,2) but no luck, how would I call the function from a cell

Comment: You're doing it right. The issue must be your macro security as it's not registering that there is a function of that name. Make sure that you are using a macro-enabled book and that your settings are medium or below.

Comment: @user: Where are you putting your code?  Should be in a regular module, not in the sheet module.

Comment: Code is in a module (not worksheet code), also my Macro settings is Enable for all macro's

Comment: I have no idea what happened but after a few month hours of fiddling around the function just started working, how I do not know. Anyway thanks as the above code and the way I was calling it above all works.    I have just one query, in the function when you use "result = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(search, cell_range, offset, opt)" is there any way to specify the worksheet to the variable cell_range as I hope to iterate through all works sheets using For Each ws In Worksheets eg something like adding ws.cell_range

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample for getting the range of a column:

```
Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
```

Customize you way, so this may help you passing your range.